# Informatica -Can we view query of an aggregate transformation

Tags: data-warehouse, informatica

hi im new to informatica ,sorry if my dount is not correct

after creating aggregator transformation ,the data transforms.actually im grouping some values .Can we get SQL query of what it is actually doing to do that

Comment: What's your RDBMS? You might be able to getthis information from some system table or use a trace analysis tool.

Answer (score 1):

Informatica PowerCentre session log only shows you the SQL query for Source Qualifier, Lookup etc. You will not get the full SQL query for Aggregator transformation from session log.

If you have access to database metadata tables, you may be able to see the query generated by Informatica in database log. For example, in Oracle database, if you know the username that informatica connects database with, you can use:

```
select session.sid
      ,session.serial#
      ,session.username
      ,session.sql_id
      ,session.sql_child_number
      ,optimizer_mode
      ,hash_value
      ,address
      ,sql_text
from   v$sqlarea sqlarea
      ,v$session session
where  session.sql_hash_value = sqlarea.hash_value
and    session.sql_address    = sqlarea.address
and    session.username = <database username here>
```

... to obtain the list sql fired by informatica user before

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned, that is not possible in Informatica PowerCenter.